# sObject type 'FieldHistoryArchive ' is not supported

Tags: soql, developer-console

When I try this SOQL query in Developer Console:

```
SELECT ParentId, FieldHistoryType, Field, Id, NewValue, OldValue FROM FieldHistoryArchive LIMIT 10
```

I get this error:

> sObject type 'FieldHistoryArchive' is not supported.

Comment: does your user have “Retain Field History” permission ?

Comment: Admin. It seems I don't have the right edition of Saleforce.

Comment: What edition are you using? Only the following editions support `BigObject`: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I have the professional.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Do you want to post the answer? Seems to be that it wasn't from a supported edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the following editions support `BigObject`: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer. If you are using an edition other than these (such as Professional) you won't be able to use `FieldHistoryArchive`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @adrianlarson answer, the following appears to be true as of V50 (Winter 21)

```
sObject type 'FieldHistoryArchive' is not supported.
```

will occur in any testmethod where the running user does not have `View All Data` permissions.  That is:

```
System.runAs(someUserWithoutViewAllDataPermission) {
   FieldHistoryArchive[] fhas = SELECT Id FROM FieldHistoryArchive Limit 1]
    ... // will fail with sObject type 'FieldHistoryArchive' is not supported.
}
```

The error does not occur in a non-test context, regardless of running user's permissions *(provided you aren't enforcing CRUD on the object before querying)*

```
FieldHistoryArchive[] fhas = SELECT Id FROM FieldHistoryArchive Limit 1]  // works
```